# How could I make a div go under the main div if length is full?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a foreach statement in jQuery that makes a div(bootstrap card) for each product in a list. Now if try to do this with just bootstrap card, after like 4 or 5 cards the card's width will be to small for anything to fit.

[image: example]

Now I don't know how to really explain this with words, but I want that if for example there are 3 divs like this:

```
| div | div | div |
```

That the 4th div has to get placed automatically under the first div, like this:

```
| div | div | div |

| div |
```

but I couldn't figure out a way to do this, I think there is a way to do this with the grid system from bootstrap but couldn't figure that out aswell

here is my code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <div id="card-deck" class="card-deck">
                 //inside of this area the foreach is running    
            </div>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `col-4`? See the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/).

Comment: @isherwood it will make the div way smaller and because of that it will be even worse then in the image. I did col-12 so i can see more product on the screen

Comment: Did you look at the docs? You can set a different number of cards for different screen sizes. If you do that properly the problem you describe doesn't occur.

Comment: If would help if you'd provide a full example. Create a demo using the editor, and load Bootstrap via CDN, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.card-deck {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 25px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.card {
    width: 350px;
}
```

the only disadvantage of this method is that, if your card width isn't proportionate to the screen size, it will leave a blank spot at the end of each line.

You can go around this by setting the card width with a percentual and by setting a `min-width` to it.